# Can't boot without an initrd

Tags: linux, kernel

I want to boot my system without an initrd and I compiled a custom kernel. I added everything I needed (filesystems, device drivers etc.) and they aren't modules. But when I try to boot without  an initrd/initramfs it says: cannot open root device or unknown-block(0 0) without initramfs. How can ı solve this?
[Error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yTDni.jpg)

lspci -k:

```
00:00.0 Host bridge: Intel Corporation 82Q35 Express DRAM Controller (rev 02)
    Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company Device 2819
    Kernel modules: intel_agp
00:01.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 82Q35 Express PCI Express Root Port (rev 02)
    Kernel driver in use: pcieport
00:03.0 Communication controller: Intel Corporation 82Q35 Express MEI Controller (rev 02)
    Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company Device 2819
    Kernel driver in use: mei_me
    Kernel modules: mei_me
00:03.2 IDE interface: Intel Corporation 82Q35 Express PT IDER Controller (rev 02)
    Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company Device 2819
    Kernel driver in use: ata_generic
    Kernel modules: pata_acpi, ata_generic
00:03.3 Serial controller: Intel Corporation 82Q35 Express Serial KT Controller (rev 02)
    Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company Device 2819
    Kernel driver in use: serial
00:19.0 Ethernet controller: Intel Corporation 82566DM-2 Gigabit Network Connection (rev 02)
    Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company Device 2818
    Kernel driver in use: e1000e
    Kernel modules: e1000e
00:1a.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation 82801I (ICH9 Family) USB UHCI Controller #4 (rev 02)
    Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company Device 2819
    Kernel driver in use: uhci_hcd
00:1a.1 USB controller: Intel Corporation 82801I (ICH9 Family) USB UHCI Controller #5 (rev 02)
    Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company Device 2819
    Kernel driver in use: uhci_hcd
00:1a.7 USB controller: Intel Corporation 82801I (ICH9 Family) USB2 EHCI Controller #2 (rev 02)
    Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company Device 2819
    Kernel driver in use: ehci-pci
00:1b.0 Audio device: Intel Corporation 82801I (ICH9 Family) HD Audio Controller (rev 02)
    Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company Device 2819
    Kernel driver in use: snd_hda_intel
    Kernel modules: snd_hda_intel
00:1c.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 82801I (ICH9 Family) PCI Express Port 1 (rev 02)
    Kernel driver in use: pcieport
00:1c.1 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 82801I (ICH9 Family) PCI Express Port 2 (rev 02)
    Kernel driver in use: pcieport
00:1d.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation 82801I (ICH9 Family) USB UHCI Controller #1 (rev 02)
    Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company Device 2819
    Kernel driver in use: uhci_hcd
00:1d.1 USB controller: Intel Corporation 82801I (ICH9 Family) USB UHCI Controller #2 (rev 02)
    Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company Device 2819
    Kernel driver in use: uhci_hcd
00:1d.2 USB controller: Intel Corporation 82801I (ICH9 Family) USB UHCI Controller #3 (rev 02)
    Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company Device 2819
    Kernel driver in use: uhci_hcd
00:1d.7 USB controller: Intel Corporation 82801I (ICH9 Family) USB2 EHCI Controller #1 (rev 02)
    Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company Device 2819
    Kernel driver in use: ehci-pci
00:1e.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 82801 PCI Bridge (rev 92)
00:1f.0 ISA bridge: Intel Corporation 82801IO (ICH9DO) LPC Interface Controller (rev 02)
    Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company Device 2819
    Kernel driver in use: lpc_ich
    Kernel modules: lpc_ich
00:1f.2 SATA controller: Intel Corporation 82801IR/IO/IH (ICH9R/DO/DH) 6 port SATA Controller [AHCI mode] (rev 02)
    Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company Device 2819
    Kernel driver in use: ahci
01:00.0 VGA compatible controller: NVIDIA Corporation GT218 [GeForce 210] (rev a2)
    Subsystem: ZOTAC International (MCO) Ltd. Device 7214
    Kernel driver in use: nouveau
    Kernel modules: nouveau
01:00.1 Audio device: NVIDIA Corporation High Definition Audio Controller (rev a1)
    Subsystem: ZOTAC International (MCO) Ltd. Device 7214
    Kernel driver in use: snd_hda_intel
    Kernel modules: snd_hda_intel
```

Comment: *"I want to boot my system without an initrd"* -- Why? A negative statement is ambiguous.  So what do you plan on using for the root filesystem?  *"I compiled a custom kernel"* -- So what are you going to use for a root filesystem?  *"But when I try to boot without an initrd/initramfs it says: ..."* -- Post the full boot log, not just one line out of context.

Answer (score 0):

You seem to have a /dev/md0 as your root device.

For your SW RAID to be assambled automatically during boot it needs:

1. To be on a partition with type FD (Linux Raid).
2. To have an older superblock (created with `--metadata=0.90` parameter added to your `mdadm --create`.

Comment: My partitions that are in RAID array are already linux_raid_member but metadata is different. And I don't suppose I can't change metadata without formatting my disks.

Comment: No, you can't. But without old metadata, you need a userspace program (and a config file) to assemble the RAID, therefore you need a ramdisk to use it as a boot device.